# Viewing CPython Code in CLion

Tags: c, cpython, clion

Sorry for a question that might appear stupid to more experienced developers: I am still a newcomer to C and C++.

I come from Python/Java development land and am trying to get a better insight into C and C++. I installed JetBrains CLion and cloned CPython mercurial repository. However when I started looking at the source code, I realized that Clion was highlighting a lot of constructs that seemed to be working. For instance:
[image]

Or

[image]

As far as I can see, Clion seems the have problem with the identation style of Python, C code, but once again, I might be wrong.

How Clion configurations can be altered for it to properly parse the CPython code?

Answer (score 7):

CPython uses GNU Autotools for the build, but that toolset is not supported by CLion. See issues [CPP-494](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-494) and [CPP-193](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-193). CLion currently supports only one build system - CMake.

You can create your own `CMakeLists.txt` file and list the sources in there. This will help CLion to understand the structure of the source tree and allow it to find the headers etc:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(cpython)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
    Python/*.c
    Parser/*.c
    Objects/*.c
    Modules/*.c)

include_directories(Include)

add_executable(cpython ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

For the actual build, use standard build tools from command line. Alternatively, custom command can be added to `CMakeLists.txt` to call `make`. See [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) for that.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the above answer you need a CMake Project to allow CLion to build Python.
In fact there is already a CMakeList.txt-files for CPython, that is maintained independently from the official sources:

https://github.com/python-cmake-buildsystem/python-cmake-buildsystem

I didn't test it with CLion but it should do the job...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that `CMakeLists.txt` is for CPython itself, but rather it's a *meta*- build system: it generates different build systems (e.g. "Visual Studio", "Unix Makefiles") for CPython, but I don't see an option for CLion or an option to generate a `CMakeLists.txt` for CPython itself.

Comment: correct, CMake builds only projects for "Visual Studio", "Makefiles" or similar. But CLion processes these Makefiles internally. So from a developers point of view it feels like CLion can work with CMakefiles.

Comment: Please refer to the README. As stated there, the CMakeLists.txt will download CPython from python.org. But this behaviour can be deactivated.